# Javascript(arrays+document.getElementById)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml, getelementbyid

So guys i have this code here:

```js
var pinakasPinakas= [2, 43, -21, 25, 34, -9, -50, 60, 12, -3];
var sum=0;
for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
    if (pinakasPinakas [i] >0){
        sum=sum+pinakasPinakas[i];
    }
}
document.getElementById("summy").innerHTML="Sum: " +sum+ ".<br>"



var multi=1;
for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
    if(pinakasPinakas[i] > 0){
    multi=multi*pinakasPinakas[i];
    }
}
document.getElementById("multipl").innerHTML="multi: " +multi+ ".<br>"


for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
if(pinakasPinakas[i]<0){
    document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML=(pinakasPinakas[i]);
    // document.write(pinakasPinakas[i])
}}
//
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
         ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: rgb(108, 162, 231);
            border: 1px solid rgb(3, 24, 63);
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: rgb(24, 12, 27);
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 5px 11px;
        }
        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            background-color: rgb(64, 102, 151);
            color: rgb(15, 30, 37);
        }
        li {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(6, 47, 100);
        }
        li:last-child { 
            border-bottom: none;
        }
        li a.active {
            background-color: rgb(0, 82, 189);
            color: rgb(25, 15, 27);
        }

        h2{color: rgb(10, 47, 116);}
        p{color: darkblue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1.html" class="active">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html"> Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Πρόσθεση & Γινόμενο θετικών αριθμών</h2>

    <p id="summy"></p>
    <p id="multipl"></p>

    <h2>Εμφάνιση αρνητικών αριθμών</h2>

    <p id="negative"></p>

    <script src="Page1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My "project" is to multiply and add the positive numbers in the array and put each one of them in an "ID", which is of course in my HTML file. So that's easy and I did that above as u
see.

So, what's the issue? After that, I should also display the negative values just like that: in another `<p id="negative">` in the html file. (-21,-9,-50,-3).
When I use the getElementById method with my innerHTML nothing appears, but sometimes when I modify that a little the last negative value is displayed (only -3). When I comment it and uncomment the `document.write()` method all negatives numbers are displayed. Why do I face such a problem with the first method? And how can i fix my code and finally use getElementById?

// thanks

Comment: Instead of `innerHTML=(pinakasPinakas[i]);` do `innerHTML+=(pinakasPinakas[i]);` You are assigning last value to innerHTML. Instead, you will have to concat the value. Alternate approach would be to use functional approaches. Split array into +ve and -ve value arrays. This will reduce unnecessary iterations and check. Then do `.innerHTML = negativeValues.join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, stay away from `document.write`. It's archaic, and has almost no practical use these days except in very special situations. [Wider discussion on this](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2016/09/avoid-using-document-write-scripts-injection/).

Now, the problem you've got currently is you're overwriting the value of `innerHTML` on *each iteration*. This is why you see only the last negative value.

Better would be to assign to `innerHTML` just once, but with the glued-together negative values, as a coherant string.

```
let negs_str = pinakasPinakas.filter(num => num < 0).join(',');
document.getElementById('negative').innerHTML = negs_str;
```

There, iteration is done implicitly for us by prototypal `filter()` method inherited by all arrays. We look at each number in the array, and keep it only if it's below 0, same as your existing logic.

Comment: it seems kinda difficult to me, because i just started writing code :(

Comment: Well, sure, that's why we're here. Ask if something isn't clear. It doesn't change the fact that I've solved your problem, though :)

Comment: Yeah I know!! Thanks a lot! I have a theoretical background and some things seem tough for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Append each element to the html: `document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML += pinakasPinakas[i]`

If you write `document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML = pinakasPinakas[i]` the html element will overwrite the content with each value from iteration and the final print will be the final element. Use `+=` if you want to display all elements from your iteration.

Also, try to reuse code. In this situation

```
var sum=0;
for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
    if (pinakasPinakas [i] >0){
        sum=sum+pinakasPinakas[i];
    }
}
document.getElementById("summy").innerHTML="Sum: " +sum+ ".<br>"

var multi=1;
for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
    if(pinakasPinakas[i] > 0){
    multi=multi*pinakasPinakas[i];
    }
 }
```

you iterate through same array twice and also you are using the same condition:
`if (pinakasPinakas [i] >0)`

Take a look at the below snippet:

```js
var pinakasPinakas = [2, 43, -21, 25, 34, -9, -50, 60, 12, -3];
var sum = 0;
var multi = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < pinakasPinakas.length; i++) {
  if (pinakasPinakas[i] > 0) {
    sum += pinakasPinakas[i];
    multi = multi * pinakasPinakas[i];
  }
}

document.getElementById("summy").innerHTML = "Sum: " + sum + ".<br>"
document.getElementById("multipl").innerHTML = "Multi: " + multi + ".<br>"


for (var i = 0; i < pinakasPinakas.length; i++) {
  if (pinakasPinakas[i] < 0) {
    document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML += pinakasPinakas[i] + ", ";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("positive").innerHTML += pinakasPinakas[i] + ", ";
  }
}
//
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(108, 162, 231);
  border: 1px solid rgb(3, 24, 63);
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(24, 12, 27);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: rgb(64, 102, 151);
  color: rgb(15, 30, 37);
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(6, 47, 100);
}

li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: rgb(0, 82, 189);
  color: rgb(25, 15, 27);
}

h2 {
  color: rgb(10, 47, 116);
}

p {
  color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#page1.html" class="active">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html"> Page 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h2>Πρόσθεση & Γινόμενο θετικών αριθμών</h2>

  <p id="summy"></p>
  <p id="multipl"></p>

  <h2>Εμφάνιση αρνητικών αριθμών</h2>

  <p id="negative">Negative: </p>
  <p id="positive">Positive: </p>

  <script src="Page1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate , u helped me so much!

Comment: Np, anytime! :)

Answer (score -1):

Just add a plus operator to append `document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML +=(pinakasPinakas[i]);`

```js
var pinakasPinakas= [2, 43, -21, 25, 34, -9, -50, 60, 12, -3];
var sum=0;
for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
    if (pinakasPinakas [i] >0){
        sum=sum+pinakasPinakas[i];
    }
}
document.getElementById("summy").innerHTML="Sum: " +sum+ ".<br>"



var multi=1;
for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
    if(pinakasPinakas[i] > 0){
    multi=multi*pinakasPinakas[i];
    }
}
document.getElementById("multipl").innerHTML="multi: " +multi+ ".<br>"


for (var i=0; i<pinakasPinakas.length; i++){
if(pinakasPinakas[i]<0){
    document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML +=(pinakasPinakas[i]);
    // document.write(pinakasPinakas[i])
}}
//
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
         ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: rgb(108, 162, 231);
            border: 1px solid rgb(3, 24, 63);
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: rgb(24, 12, 27);
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 5px 11px;
        }
        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            background-color: rgb(64, 102, 151);
            color: rgb(15, 30, 37);
        }
        li {
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(6, 47, 100);
        }
        li:last-child { 
            border-bottom: none;
        }
        li a.active {
            background-color: rgb(0, 82, 189);
            color: rgb(25, 15, 27);
        }

        h2{color: rgb(10, 47, 116);}
        p{color: darkblue;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1.html" class="active">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html"> Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Πρόσθεση & Γινόμενο θετικών αριθμών</h2>

    <p id="summy"></p>
    <p id="multipl"></p>

    <h2>Εμφάνιση αρνητικών αριθμών</h2>

    <p id="negative"></p>

    <script src="Page1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a typographical question and a mere comment is fine for it. Answering such questions is a bad practice

Comment: @Rajesh I dont think it is a typo. He might not know how to append the values to the DOM.